# Disassemble unloaded module

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

Got a stack trace that ends in an unloaded module. To make sure the stack makes sense I would like to disassemble the unloaded module (in other to check whether a call can start on the address given (access violation: attempt to read from an invalid address)). I can load the module (windbg):

```
.reload Unloaded.Dll=base,size
```

But after this reload I’m not able to disassemble the code. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help! GMore

Comment: Shot in the dark but if you have a copy of the dll then add its location to windbg's executable path `.exepath+ c:\myBins`, then `.reload` then try to disassemble.

Comment: Are you sure it goes into an unloaded module? It must be a crippled function pointer that happens to point into the area previously occupied by a module - can you "anonymize" the stack trace and share it here?

Comment: If you are performing user-mode debugging and want to load a module that is not part of the target application's module list, you must include the `/s` option, as the following example [shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564805(v=vs.85).aspx). `0:000> .reload /s ntdll.dll`

Comment: It is weird but urlmon!CTransation::DispatchReport() seems to call a routine in Msoxmlmf.dll which is unloaded at that that moment. The exeption address is in an area where Msoxmlmf.dll was loaded (according to windbg).

Comment: @Gerard, what do you mean by "not able to disassemble" -- the segment is missing or something else? Also, what does `!address` show for the address you want to disassemble?

Comment: @MarcSherman your shot in the dark is some hit, pitty most is filled with 0x0. Guess loading code is too hard.

Comment: @SevaTitov !address issues: Unloaded module that overloaded the region in the past.

Comment: @Gerard how are you obtaining the address in the first place?

Comment: @MarcSherman !analyze -v shows the address, an access violation: attempt to read from an invalid address. The address is on the stack far above the stackpointer where the exception is handled together with C0000005 etc. The call from DispatchReport() is indirect: call [eax], so it MIGHT be right. Actually I would like to know whether a call starts at the fault-address given (to be sure). Something like a push of the framepoiner, etc.

Comment: @Gerard `lm` will show you unloaded DLLs along with their load addreses at the end of its output. Did you use the same load address for the base when you loaded it with `.reload Unloaded.Dll=base,size`? That would hopefully make sure that eax is pointing to the correct offset within your DLL.

Comment: @MarcSherman sure I did. A hard way to verify is to make a dump of the running process and hope the Dll in question is loaded.

Comment: @Gerard Subtract the load address from [eax]. This will give you an offset. Using a second instance of windbg load your dll as a crash dump (this works) and then add the offset to the load address in the second windbg. Then try disassembling this address in the second windbg.

Comment: @MarcSherman Great tip! It is 2 instructions (3 bytes) off a start of a routine (a push ebp). Consider it a hit...!

Comment: @Gerard Interesting. Which 2 instructions precede the `push ebp`? Is `mov edi,edi` one of them? Also, you can `uf <addr_of_push_ebp_instruction>` to disassemble the whole function.

Comment: @MarcSherman No it is the end of another routine, a pop ebp followed by  ret 10H. Still not sure if it is a sound scenario.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23409/discussion-between-marc-sherman-and-gerard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip from Marc Sherman (see comments above):
With windbg your can load a dll as a crash dump. After the load type the "lm" command and disassemble on the address wanted relative to the base given.