# Get the Name of Function called using exe, pdb, and windbg logs w/o symbols loaded

Tags: windbg

I've spent all day and haven't been able to get the symbols to load. The stack trace in windbg still shows hex addresses of my app and fails to verify checksum for my exe.

I have the hex address, windbg logs, the exe and the pdb file. Can I not manually figure out the last function called.

And here is the log should you be interested :-

```
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for vrfcore.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for combase.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for oleaut32.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MYapp.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MYapp.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for user32.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for appcore.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for appengine.dll - 
***** OS symbols are WRONG. Please fix symbols to do analysis.

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that   ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: ntdll!_PEB                                    ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for kernel32.dll - 
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that   ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: nt!IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32                         ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ole32.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for KERNELBASE.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mswsock.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+2467
7748a947 eb11            jmp     ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x247a (7748a95a)

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 7748a947 (ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x00002467)
   ExceptionCode: c0000374
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 7749e1e8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  MYapp.exe

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
You can run '.symfix; .reload' to try to fix the symbol path and load symbols.

FAULTING_MODULE: 773b0000 ntdll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50108a69

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000374 - A heap has been corrupted.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000374 - A heap has been corrupted.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  7749e1e8

APP:  myapp.exe

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7748bbff to 7748a947

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0072b7b4 7748bbff c0000374 7749e1e8 0072b7f8 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x2467
0072b7c4 7748ac55 00000002 97dca43f 03d30000 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x371f
0072b7f8 77425b89 00000008 03d30000 082a15e8 ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x2775
0072b82c 6ff9a6df 03d30000 00000000 082a15f0 ntdll!RtlCreateUserThread+0x4549
0072b844 771b3da8 03d30000 00000000 082a15f0 vrfcore!VerifierSetAPIClassName+0x116
0072b858 7539d0cc 772bd7c8 082a15f0 082a15f0 combase!CoGetMalloc+0x570
0072b874 753344cc 00000010 75334490 082a15f4 oleaut32!VarFormatFromTokens+0x15a25
0072b888 00ed41ad 082a15f4 e198556c 0072b9b8 oleaut32!SysFreeString+0x3c
0072b988 00edad3f 0072b9b4 0072b9f4 06a97188 MYapp+0x141ad
0072bb1c 00ee00f7 06502f40 0072be08 e19857ac MYapp+0x1ad3f
0072bb48 00ecb4a8 0072bb78 0072be08 e1985740 MYapp+0x200f7
0072bba4 00ee0902 0072be94 0072be08 e198571c MYapp+0xb4a8
0072bbf8 00ec87b8 05c9a530 e19850fc 00000000 MYapp+0x20902
0072bc18 00edccb3 0072be08 e198508c 0000000a MYapp+0x87b8
0072bc68 00edc98f 0072bdec e198509c 05c9964c MYapp+0x1ccb3
0072bf0c 00ec5dc7 0072c044 e1982de4 0072c264 MYapp+0x1c98f
0072c100 757477d8 002a020c 0000c1be 00000000 MYapp+0x5dc7
0072c12c 757478cb 00ec5af0 002a020c 0000c1be user32!gapfnScSendMessage+0x4e0
0072c1a8 7574f139 00ec5af0 00ec5af0 00000000 user32!gapfnScSendMessage+0x5d3
0072c210 7574aaa6 04819c60 00000000 0000c1be user32!PostMessageA+0x15e
0072c23c 6ee5b057 002a020c 0000c1be 00000000 user32!SendMessageW+0x52
....

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
oleaut32!VarFormatFromTokens+15a25
7539d0cc e98573f9ff      jmp     oleaut32!VariantInit+0xb46 (75334456)

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  oleaut32!VarFormatFromTokens+15a25

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: oleaut32

IMAGE_NAME:  oleaut32.dll

BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c0000374_oleaut32.dll!VarFormatFromTokens
---------
```

o/p of reload /f after adding the symbol path to dir containing Myapp.pdb

```
0:000> !sym noisy; .reload /f MYApp.exe
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
DBGHELP: none - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for MYapp.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for MYapp.exe
DBGHELP: MYapp - no symbols loaded
```

Comment: Have you tried `.symfix;.reload`? This sets the source path to http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols and then forces a reload.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I've tried that to no effect. Also I have the symbols local.

Comment: Ok, have you built the pdbs without private symbols stripped? This will be a visual studio setting in the project settings->Linker-->Debugging "strip private symbols", set this to blank or /PDBSTRIPPED see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd.aspx

Comment: Thanks Again! It is blank already. The non blank are Generate Debug Info Yes. Generate Map File No. Map Exports No.

Comment: Btw, it shows address regions for two dll's (used by myapp) overlap. Is that an issue?

Comment: Type `!sym noisy; reload /f MYapp.exe` and add output to you question.

Comment: Try use [chkmatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) `-c MYapp.exe MYapp.pdb` to check whether an executable and debug information file match.

Comment: Thanks didn't know abt this. It says Result: Matched. Could the paths be wrong. How can I check if they are right?

Comment: You do not have .dmp file, only logs?

Comment: Try .reload MYapp.exe [= base,size] or try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522596/disassemble-unloaded-module